# Application written Delphi XE8 touch in edit boxes keyboard not appear in Windows 10

Tags: delphi, keyboard, touch, windows-10, delphi-xe8

I have Win 32 bit desktop app written in Delphi XE8 with subscription update 1. Windows 10 is set to tablet mode. When I touch edit boxes or memo boxes on my app, keyboard does not appear. 
It only appears if I touch a password field e.g. edit control with password char set to * or editable combobox. 
When I run notepad.exe and touch it, keyboard appears, but not for any editable controls on my app ... except for password fields... What is the trick here?

Comment: See [Automatically pop up tablet touch keyboard on WinForms input focus](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36179917/850848).